# Quotient ring $R/I$, $R= \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-10}]$, $I =(\sqrt{-10})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

To show $I =(\sqrt{-10})$ is not prime in $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-10}]$, there is a direct method, i.e. show that $2$ and $5$ are not in $I$ but their product $10$ is. However, I struggled to prove the result using the idea of quotient ring. As I understand it, $R/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, but this would give rise to $I$ being prime but not maximal, as $\mathbb{Z}$ is ID but not a field. Where have I gone wrong saying that $R/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $R/I$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. Eg, the image of $10$ is already zero in the quotient..

Comment: I got my head around now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In this case $R/I$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z$, not $\Bbb Z$.  Note that $10\in I$ means that its image in $R/I$ must be zero.  This means that $R/I$ is isomorphic to some quotient of $\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z$.  Showing that you get $\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z$ instead of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ essentially the same task as showing $10\in I$ but $2\not\in I, 5\not\in I$.

Comment: oh I see, I have no idea why I failed to see such simple variation of phrasing. Thanks!